# What's up with my code?

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

Sorry if my code isn't well written or anything because I'm new to Arduino and coding in C, but what is wrong with my code?

```
int sidepin = 2;
int LED = 5;
int val;
void setup() {
  pinMode(sidepin, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  val = digitalRead(sidepin);
  if(val = 0)
  {
    pinMode(LED, HIGH);
  }
  else(val > 0) 
  {
    pinMode(LED, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please help the helpers help you by asking a more specific question than "what's up..." If you need help with compiler errors, say so, and report at least some of the message and the location of it. If you're asking about run-time behavior, please state what you expected it to do and what it actually did. You can get lots of good help here but please try to direct your readers to the specific problem. The guide to [asking good questions](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) has a lot of good suggestions.

Comment: `else(){}` looks like bad syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IF statement, you're using: `(val = 0)`, and I believe you meant `(val == 0)`.

Also, you're using `else(val > 0)` and `else` doesn't need any argument. So the fixed code should look like:

```
int sidepin = 2;
int LED = 5;
int val;
void setup() {
  pinMode(sidepin, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  val = digitalRead(sidepin);
  if(val == LOW)
  {
    pinMode(LED, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    pinMode(LED, LOW);
  }
}
```